# Invalid credentials error when attempting PUT to a HTTPS site

Tags: vba, https, http-headers, winhttprequest

I am attempting to submit a file on a HTTPS site using VBA, but I am having issues with the authentication. (When viewed, the site has the standard field for file name, with a "browse" button, and a "submit" button.)

I've tried a couple of things... first, I used an `InternetExplorer.Application` object, but the element type that I need to populate is `file`, and I've read that this is not directly accessible via code for security reasons. (Sorry I don't have the link for a citation...)

Next suggestion was to use a `WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1` object and a `PUT` request. When I do that however, the response from the site is a 401, invalid authentication error.

I'm able to access the site without entering any credentials when I'm browsing normally. I've looked at some questions about HTTPS headers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18264601/how-to-send-a-correct-authorization-header-for-basic-authentication?lq=1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716990/http-basic-authentication-credentials-passed-in-url-and-encryption?lq=1), but haven't been able to get them to work. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

```
Dim objHTTP As Object
Dim URL As String
Set objHTTP = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
URL = "https://siteImUploadingTo.domain.com/site"
objHTTP.Open "PUT", URL, False

objHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
objHTTP.Send ("_fileToPost=" & ThisWorkbook.Path & \filename.PDF&_pagesSelection=1-100")
Debug.Print objHTTP.ResponseText 'returns a 401 invalid credentials error.
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, it appears that you're missing a `.SetCredentials` call, after `.Open` and before `.Send`:

```vb
objHTTP.SetCredentials username, password, HTTPREQUEST_SETCREDENTIALS_FOR_SERVER
```

I ran your code on my test environment, and I also had to set the `WinHttpRequestOption_SslErrorIgnoreFlags` option to be able to ignore all SSL errors ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12080824/how-to-ignore-invalid-certificates-with-iwinhttprequest#12081003)):

```
objHTTP.Option(WinHttpRequestOption_SslErrorIgnoreFlags) = &H3300 //SslErrorFlag_Ignore_All
```

At last, I don't think your `Send` command will work at actually posting a file to your server. I recommend you using the code below, adapted from this [blog post](https://wqweto.wordpress.com/2011/07/12/vb6-using-wininet-to-post-binary-file/).

```vb
' add a reference to "Microsoft WinHTTP Services, version 5.1"
Public Function PostFile( _
    sUrl As String, sFileName As String, sUsername As String, sPassword As String, _
    Optional bIgnoreAllSslErrors As Boolean = False, Optional bAsync As Boolean _
) As String
    Const HTTPREQUEST_SETCREDENTIALS_FOR_SERVER = 0
    Const STR_BOUNDARY  As String = "3fbd04f5-b1ed-4060-99b9-fca7ff59c113"
    Dim nFile           As Integer
    Dim baBuffer()      As Byte
    Dim sPostData       As String
    Dim browser         As WinHttp.WinHttpRequest

    '--- read file
    nFile = FreeFile
    Open sFileName For Binary Access Read As nFile
    If LOF(nFile) > 0 Then
        ReDim baBuffer(0 To LOF(nFile) - 1) As Byte
        Get nFile, , baBuffer
        sPostData = StrConv(baBuffer, vbUnicode)
    End If
    Close nFile

    '--- prepare body
    sPostData = _
        "--" & STR_BOUNDARY & vbCrLf & _
            "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""uploadfile""; filename=""" & Mid$(sFileName, InStrRev(sFileName, "\") + 1) & """" & vbCrLf & _
            "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
            sPostData & vbCrLf & _
        "--" & STR_BOUNDARY & "--"

    '--- post
    Set browser = New WinHttpRequest
    browser.Open "POST", sUrl, bAsync

    browser.SetCredentials sUsername, sPassword, HTTPREQUEST_SETCREDENTIALS_FOR_SERVER

    If bIgnoreAllSslErrors Then
        ' https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12080824/how-to-ignore-invalid-certificates-with-iwinhttprequest#12081003
        browser.Option(WinHttpRequestOption_SslErrorIgnoreFlags) = &H3300
    End If

    browser.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" & STR_BOUNDARY
    browser.Send pvToByteArray(sPostData)
    If Not bAsync Then
        PostFile = browser.ResponseText
    End If
End Function

Private Function pvToByteArray(sText As String) As Byte()
    pvToByteArray = StrConv(sText, vbFromUnicode)
End Function
```

If you need to send additional fields, you can do so by modifying the sPostData variable:

```vb
sPostData = _
    "--" & STR_BOUNDARY & vbCrLf & _
        "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""field1""" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
        field1 & vbCrLf & _
    "--" & STR_BOUNDARY & vbCrLf & _
        "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""field2""" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
        field2 & vbCrLf & _
    "--" & STR_BOUNDARY & vbCrLf & _
        "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""uploadfile""; filename=""" & Mid$(FileFullPath, InStrRev(FileFullPath, "\") + 1) & """" & vbCrLf & _
        "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
        sPostData & vbCrLf & _
    "--" & STR_BOUNDARY & "--"
```